# Stored Proc with multiple parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need a SP which can take some 24 input parameters to insert a record into a table. One way of sending multiple parameters is by using XML datatype. Any other best practice for sending multiple input parameter in SQL SP?

Any advise is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're inserting only a fixed number of records, than you can define 24 parameters in your SP. This way you can get some compile-time checking, also you can define not-null, null or a default value for each parameter for greater flexibility.

I woudn't use XML datatype unless I have variable number of arguments or I must simulate parameter arrays (like in insert multiple orderlines at the same time).

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or higher there is support for [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). You can check this link [for using table-valued params with .NET SqlCient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx), too

Answer (score 1):

Vasile Bujac's answer is excellent and I agree with everything.  But it may be worth adding that Sommarskog, a luminary MVP, has some very good articles on mimicing an array in SQL Server that may be very applicable to your situation.  You can find them here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html